# Disable comment count next to title(Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, meta

I find out that there's `comments_popup_link()` in `function.php` like below. 
Because I'd like to delete comment count, I change '0 comments', '1 comment' & '% comments' into ' ' (empty).

```js
function outspoken_comments($echo = true, $separator = true) {
 $result = '';
 if ($separator) {
  $result .= '<span class="separator">'.(is_single() ? '/' : '&middot;').'</span>';
 }
 if (comments_open()) {
  $result .= '<span class="leave-reply">';
  ob_start();
  comments_popup_link(__('0 comments', 'outspoken'), __('1 comment', 'outspoken'), __('% comments', 'outspoken')); 
// I change all 'X comments' into '' (empty)

  $output = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  $result .= $output.'</span>';
 }
 else $result .= '<span>'.__('Comments closed', 'outspoken').'</span>';

 if ($echo) {
  echo $result;
  return null;
 }
 return $result;
}
```

[image: title and meta without comment count]

It worked, but I don't think it's a good way since the function still need to run and it's just *hidden*. What is the best way to completely disable the comment count?

Comment: By deleting `outspoken_comments`?

Comment: @Filipe I'd tried delete function related to `outspoken_comments`, but the page shows only what is before the comment count, like page footer and title. The browser can't load which is after the comment count, like post content, widget or social media sharing button.

Comment: Hmm, have you removed the action link of that function?

Comment: @Filipe You mean the things inside `{ }` or `return`?

Comment: Nope, in the function.php might have a add_action calling that comment function

Comment: @Filipe Whoa, that's right! I saw [this](http://jsbin.com/caxaniz/edit?js) in function.php, and it worked well and not calling comment function in entry-meta! Thanks man!!!